# How to properly reason about the bounds of $x, y$ in integration over triangles?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Suppose I have to integrate $$\int_T f(x, y) \text{d}x\text{d}y$$

where $T$ is a triangle, and the vertexes are given. How do you construct the bounds for the integral?
I find myself stuck every time due to some lack of clarity.

For example, say $T$ is the triangle with vertices $(0, 0)$, $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 1)$.

For sure, I would draw a picture on the cartesian plane, otherwise I would find it like impossible to understand the bonds mentally.
Yet after having drawn them, I would still have doubts.

I know, in the case above, that $x$ runs from $0$ to $1$.
In the same way, I understand that $y$ follows the $y = x$ paths, but here to say what are the correct bonds for $y$?

I find two possibilities: $y \in (1, x)$ or $y\in (x, 1)$, because when $x = 0$ then $y = 1$ (it's a vertex) but also when $x = 1$ we have $y = 1$.

I'm so confused!

Is there a general way to reason about those problems in order to understand well the path and the order of the bounds?

Thank you!

Comment: Think about trying to touch every point in the triangle (not just on the edges, but within the triangle). First, choose a point $(x,0)$ on the $x$-axis between $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. Then, choose any $y$ with $0 \leq y \leq x$ and move up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [double integral over an arbitrary triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954409/double-integral-over-an-arbitrary-triangle)

Comment: For the $y$ bounds, you always go from the *bottom* curve to the *top* curve (i.e., in the *increasing* $y$ direction). So from the line $y=x$ to the line $y=1$ in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I think it will help to first write your triangle $T$ in set notation as follows:
$$
T=\{ (x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\colon 0\leq x\leq y\leq 1\}.
$$
Try to make a drawing and see, that this is correct. So $(x,y)\in T$ if and only if $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $x\leq y\leq 1$ or equivalently $0\leq y\leq 1$ and $0\leq x\leq y$. Thus,
$$
\int_T f(x,y)\,dx dy=\int_0^1 \int_x^1 f(x,y)\, dy dx=\int_0^1 \int_0^y f(x,y)\, dx dy.
$$

Comment: This is for the particular case ; for the general case, you should push your explanation into a *more operational* answer : what do we do practically when we are given the$(x,y)$ coordinates of the 3 vertices ?